# I keep flying past the attacking players on defense in FIFA? How do I fix this?

Tags: fifa-14, fifa-15

Basically, there are several times on defense where I will point my controller towards the defensive player, but as I get closer within a feet, I then fly like 3 yards past him, leaving him wide open.

How can I stop doing this?